# I need help understanding why the return value is different from what I expected. I am using the cmd module

Tags: python, cmd

I have two files that I am trying to work with.  `menu.py` has the menus that `program.py` imports.

**menu.py:**

```
import cmd,sys

user = 'no one'

class loginMenu(cmd.Cmd):
    def postloop(self):
        user = 'lilith'
        return user
    intro="""login menu"""
    def do_smtoggle(self,person):
        return True

    def do_quit(self,person):
        sys.exit()

class storeMenu(cmd.Cmd):
    intro="""store menu"""
    def do_whoami(self,person):
        print 'storemenu ' + user
    def do_quit(self,person):
        quit = True
        return quit
```

**program.py**:

```
from menu import *
import cmd,sys

lm = loginMenu()
sm = storeMenu()

while True:
    lm.cmdloop()
    print user
    sm.cmdloop()
```

I expect that when program.py gets to `print user` it will print `lilith` but instead it prints `no one`.  Why is this?  `postloop()` is defined in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.postloop) as a method that executes when `cmdloop()` is about to return so I thought it would return the value of `user` as `lilith` and then `lilith` would be printed but it just prints `no one`.

edit: It has been recommended that I not use globals.  I am reading [this](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) to find out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the assignment to `user` here:

```
def postloop(self):
    user = 'lilith'
    return user
```

is acting on a local instance of the var.  To affect the global var `user`, you would need to add a:

```
global user
```

to the top of that function.  Though I wouldn't recommend it, as there are usually better ways to do things than to use globals.

One note about globals and python.  While you can't assign a value to a global var without the `global` keyword, you can read global (and other non-local) scopes, without it.  This allows you to make closures.

Answer (score 2):

`cmd` has nothing to do with this. `user = 'lilith'` introduces a new, local binding. To rebind the global name, you need to do:

```
global user
user = 'lilith'
```

Also, you should avoid globals.